# como ler o conteúdo de um json pelo VUE

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Preciso receber um arquivo `json` pelo `input type file` e ler o conteúdo deste arquivo no front sem precisar realizar uma requisição para o servidor.

```
<input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()" />

handleFileUpload() {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
  reader.onload = function() {
   console.log(reader.result)
  };
  reader.readAsText(file)
},
```

Consigo imprimir no console o arquivo mas não colocar em uma variável para poder utilizar dentro do código.

Answer (score 2):

Então, eu fiz alguns testes aqui e consegui fazer dessa forma:

```
methods: {
    parse(){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this.onReaderLoad;
      reader.readAsText(this.$refs.myFile.files[0]);
    },
    onReaderLoad(event) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(event.target.result))
    }
}
```

Ele cria uma instância do FileReader, adiciono um callback para quando terminar de ler o arquivo e voilà!

Segue código exemplo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-9swn8